# What is wrong with this substring function

Tags: c++, string

Substring is not outputting anything when I try to put it out. I should be getting some output

see code below but basically I put 2 parameters ints a and b where a is the starting position and b is the number of characters to copy. but the function jumps to the end

```
   DSString DSString :: substring(int a, int b){
        if(a >= 0 && b > a){
            char* tmp = new char[b - a + 1];
            strncpy(tmp,data,b-a);
            DSString result(tmp);
            delete [] tmp;
            return result;
        }
       return DSString("");
    }
```

for "Hello" and parameters 3 and 2 expected to see "lo" but instead is returning an empty string.

Comment: For parameters 3 and 2, is `(a >= 0 && b > a)`?

Comment: as soon as I posted this I just realized that lol

Comment: now strncpy is returning a segmentation fault what is up with that?

Comment: assuming that the constructor of `DSString` requires a null-terminated string, this fails because `strncpy` doesn't put a null terminator. A much better solution would be to modify this "DSString" to allow taking a view (if it doesn't already)

Comment: If you are still having trouble please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You are writing the function as if b is the end position rather than how far the end position is from the start.

Comment: What do `a` and `b` represent? Likely `strncpy(tmp,data,b-a);` does not copy the *nul-terminating* character resulting in UB with `DSString result(tmp);`

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the following points:

- You have to use `a` twice - for calculating number of copied characters (I see this) and to find beginning of substring (I expect something like `data + a`)
- Because "*No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num.*" ([see C++ references](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/?kw=strncpy)) you have to add null-character to `tmp` after copying data.
- Data type of `data` have to be `char *` (Actually I do not see the definition)
- Memory should be allocated for `char * data` in the constructor `DSString::DSString` (also not shown in the question)

Answer (score 0):

The way you have implemented your input parameters, `a` is a starting index and `b` is an ending index. But you are not validating whether either index exceeds the bounds of the `data` buffer being copied from. In fact, you are not even using the starting index at all when copying from the `data` buffer.

Also, although you are allocating the `tmp` buffer to include space for a null terminator, you are not telling `strncpy()` that there is room for a null terminator, so it does not output a null terminator, and you are not providing a null terminator of your own.

Try this instead:

```cpp
DSString DSString::substring(int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= 0 && start < end)
    {
        int len = strlen(data);
        if (end > len) end = len;
        int count = end - start;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            char* tmp = new char[count + 1];
            memcpy(tmp, data + start, count);
            tmp[count] = '\0';
            DSString result(tmp);
            delete [] tmp;
            /* alternatively:
            DSString result;
            result.data = tmp;
            */
            return result;
        }
    }
    return DSString("");
}
```

However, given the example you have provided, you are actually expecting the 2nd parameter to be a count, not an index, so try this instead:

```cpp
DSString DSString::substring(int start, int count)
{
    if (start >= 0 && count > 0)
    {
        int len = strlen(data);
        if ((start + count) > len)
            count = len - start;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            char* tmp = new char[count + 1];
            memcpy(tmp, data + start, count);
            tmp[count] = '\0';
            DSString result(tmp);
            delete [] tmp;
            /* alternatively:
            DSString result;
            result.data = tmp;
            */
            return result;
        }
    }
    return DSString("");
}
```

That being said, you can avoid the `tmp` buffer altogether by adding a constructor that takes a `char*` and length as input:

```cpp
DSString::DSString(char *d, int count)
{
    if (d && count > 0)
    {
        data = new char[count + 1];
        memcpy(data, d, count);
        data[count] = '\0';
    }
    else
        data =  nullptr;
}
```

Then you can do one of these as needed:

```cpp
DSString DSString::substring(int start, int end)
{
    if (start >= 0 && start < end)
    {
        int len = strlen(data);
        if (end > len) end = len;
        return DSString(data + start, end - start);
    }
    return DSString("");
}
```

```cpp
DSString DSString::substring(int start, int count)
{
    if (start >= 0 && count > 0)
    {
        int len = strlen(data);
        if ((start + count) > len)
            count = len - start;
        return DSString(data + start, count);
    }
    return DSString("");
}
```